# Invalid pointer when using global variables/lambda functions in python?

Tags: python, pointers, memory, lambda

I've come across a bit of a strange bug, and I'm really not sure what's causing it.

I have a list containing lambda functions, and i have set this list to be a global variable as shown below. The global variables are then referenced within the "residual" function with the required function inputs.

```
from numpy import array

from math import exp

from guppy import hpy   
hp = hpy()
hp.setrelheap()

rate_array = [[0, "4.91*(10**-22)*(T_m**4)"],                                                
              [1, "1.4*(10**-18)*(T_m**0.928)*exp(-T_m/16200)"]]  

global k

k = [0,0]

for i in range(0,2):

    k[i] = (eval('lambda T_m,T_r,Z_initial: ' + rate_array[i][1]))


def residual(t,y,yd):

    Z_initial = 10

    res_0 = -k[1](y[2],y[3], Z_initial)*y[0]
    res_1 = -k[0](y[2],y[3],Z_initial)*y[1]

    return array([res_0,res_1 ])



y = [0,0,0,0]
yd= [0,0,0,0]
t=0

residual(t,y,yd)


print("\nMemory statistics are as follows:\n")
print hp.heap()
```

Running the residual function seems to give a invalid pointer error, or a segmentation fault. Every now and then the code runs, but most of the time it does not. I don't see anything wrong with the code, so im not sure whats going on. Is there anything glaringly obvious?

EXTRA: I realize this is a strange way to go about it, but to explain: the "rate_array" contains strings as it is pickled/unpickled depending on whether or not the user wants to edit it.

Also the residual function is integrated by 3rd party software and it only allows the 3 inputs shown, so i can't just pass the array as an input into the function as normal. I also cannot append it to include the rate_array, as it wont take lambda functions as an acceptable type.

Normally the lambda functions/expressions could just be in the residual function itself, as just extra lines of code, but then its not possible for the user to edit them before the code runs.....Its such a mess!

EDIT: apologies, i heavily cut down the code to try and make it simpler to explain, but in the process just typed stuff that was plain wrong, now corrected.

The error code:

```
*** glibc detected *** python: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002a7aa50 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x7fd857ddbb96]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guppy/sets/setsc.so(+0xbeeb)[0x7fd841bd1eeb]
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/guppy/sets/setsc.so(+0xbf73)[0x7fd841bd1f73]
python[0x48abf9]
python[0x48a9de]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x52c)[0x45fb2c]
python(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0xcb7)[0x4602b7]
python(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x199)[0x467209]
python(PyEval_EvalCode+0x32)[0x4d0242]
python[0x5102bb]
python(PyRun_FileExFlags+0x9a)[0x44a466]
python(PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags+0x2bc)[0x44a97a]
python(Py_Main+0xb36)[0x44b6bc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7fd857d7e76d]
python[0x4ce0ad]
```

Comment: When exactly does it error out? What error do you get?

Comment: Are you using `from numpy import *`?  It'd be nice to try to reproduce this ...

Comment: Also, this line seems like a syntax error:  `res_0 = -k[1](y[8],y[7], Z _initial)*y[4]`

Comment: `global` doesn't go there - it goes in the function using the global. Also there appear to be some typos in the code. I'd suggest giving a complete example with all variables defined.

Comment: What is `Z_initial` in the `residual` function? If I try to run the above code I get the error that it's not defined. Please make sure the code sample is runnable!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Hmm if I run it it works fine. I changed the last line to `print residual(t,y,yd)` and I get `[-0. -0.]` printed on the command line... would your code work without the `eval`? Maybe it's an issue of trying to use 64-bit python with 32-bit numpy or something?

Comment: Is that really the code you're executing? It works fine on me. Also, how are you executing it? It seems strange that guppy is involved, since it shouldn't be loaded in the first place if you run this file with `python file.py`.

Comment: After some experimenting the issue seems to be with the code between "global k" and the for loop, no idea why though. Im checking through the rest just to see if theres a conflict, but Im pretty stumped.

Comment: And well, this is heavily cut down, if i posted the whole thing it'd just be too much, but its definitely the area thats causing the issue. There is memory profiling occurring,and Ive added the code relating to this. The thing is its always been fine before, not sure why it doesn't like it now.  Its being run from the terminal on ubuntu, nothing fancy.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Guppy.